# setting up batman adv

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I am trying to configure batman-adv. I am using two raspberry pi 3a+. I have Raspberry Pi Os bookworm (not lite version) installed on them.
Each raspberry has a wifi adapter (rtl8812bu chip used this driver: https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702) which they use to connect to my home wifi network for ssh configuration.
I configure Batman using this guide https://github.com/binnes/WiFiMeshRaspberryPi/blob/master/part1/PIMESH.md. First raspberry (raspberrypi3 also configured as gateway (ROUTE.md in guide))

However, after all the configuration, the `batctl n` command gives an empty list of neighbors:

```
xrou@raspberrypi3:~ ~ $ sudo batctl n
[B.A.T.M.A.N. adv 2022.3, MainIF/MAC: wlan0/b8:27:eb:f4:74:f2 (bat0/f6:58:1e:21:76:54 BATMAN_IV)]
IF Neighbor last-seen
```

Second raspberry:

```
xrou@rpimesh:~ ~ $ sudo batctl n
[B.A.T.M.A.N. adv 2022.3, MainIF/MAC: wlan0/b8:27:eb:95:77:3a (bat0/a2:eb:4d:33:a5:04 BATMAN_IV)]
IF Neighbor last-seen
```

on both raspberry pi the `batctl if` command produces the following:

```
xrou@raspberrypi3:~ $ sudo batctl if
wlan0: active

xrou@rpimesh:~ $ sudo batctl if
wlan0: active
```

This is what the ifconfig and iwconfig commands produce on the first raspberry:

```
xrou@raspberrypi3:~ $ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

wlan1     IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"RT-5GPON-6155"  Nickname:"WIFI@RTL88X2BU"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 44:13:D0:B7:61:56
          Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=64/100  Signal level=47/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

bat0      no wireless extensions.

xrou@raspberrypi3:~ $ sudo ifconfig
bat0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1468
        inet 192.168.199.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.199.255
        inet6 fe80::f046:83ff:feae:a4c8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f2:46:83:ae:a4:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 39  bytes 1638 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1  bytes 90 (90.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 53 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 99  bytes 8743 (8.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 99  bytes 8743 (8.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:f4:74:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::63ec:6dc4:66e2:2a58  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:91:64:06:3e:19  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 483  bytes 120813 (117.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 151  bytes 26303 (25.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And second raspberry

```
xrou@rpimesh:~ $ sudo ifconfig
bat0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1468
        inet6 fe80::f4d4:56ff:fecd:a80b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f6:d4:56:cd:a8:0b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 47  bytes 1974 (1.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1  bytes 90 (90.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 28 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 101  bytes 8827 (8.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 101  bytes 8827 (8.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:95:77:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::9133:2fec:b268:894a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:91:64:06:3d:e4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 488  bytes 123198 (120.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 117  bytes 20234 (19.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

xrou@rpimesh:~ $ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

wlan1     IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"RT-5GPON-6155"  Nickname:"WIFI@RTL88X2BU"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 44:13:D0:B7:61:56
          Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode                                                                                                             :open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=73/100  Signal level=67/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

bat0      no wireless extensions.
```

For some reason the wlan0 interface is not configured properly. This is what it should be (from guide)

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11 ESSID: "call-code-mesh"  
        Mode:Ad-Hoc Frequency:2.462 GHz Cell: 3A:BC:74:3B:A1:D9
        Tx-Power=31 dBm
        Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
        Power Management:on
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, can you help me?

Comment: You are using an OS not recommended for the Pi3A+ which uses a different network manager and running an archived application which uses an even older networking system. It is hardly surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: @Milliways Sure i can use raspberry pi 4, but is pi os important the device it runs on? How do i make a mesh network? i heard about yggdrasil, can it work on my raspberry 3?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem setting up batman-adv on a Raspberry Pi 3b+. What finally worked for me was installing the Buster version of Raspbian. I believe the tutorial you are using is based on the old network manager used in that OS, which was changed on newer versions.